# Return associated model attribute as current model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have an association between ProcessingStatus and Order that looks like this:

Order belongs_to ProcessingStatus
ProcessingStatus has_one Order

When I return an Order, I want to be able to get the ProcessingStatus 'name' attribute as the 'status' attribute of my JSON response.

So, right now, for the following GET call at /orders/73,

```
render :json => @order.to_json(:only => [:id], :include => {:processing_status => {:only => [:name]}})
```

I get this:

```
{
    "id": 73,
    "processing_status": {
        "name": 'processing'
    }
}
```

And I am looking for a way to get this:

```
{
    "id": 73,
    "status": 'processing'

}
```

Anyway on doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a method on your model that returns the status as the value of `processing_status.name` and then include that in your json:

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  def status
    self.processing_status.try(:name)
  end

end
```

And then include that in your `to_json` call:

```
@order.to_json(only: :id, methods: :status)
```

Alternatively you could add the status to a hash that gets converted to json:

```
@order.as_json(only: :id).merge(status: @order.processing_status.try(:name)).to_json
```

I've used `.try(:name)` in case `processing_status` is nil but you might not need that. The behaviour is slightly different in the two cases as the first will not include `status` in the json and the second will include `"status":null`.